# LinearLayout isn't aligning to right

Tags: android, view, alignment

I have this xml code:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="140dp">
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageprofile"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"
        android:layout_margin="35dp" />
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFullName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUserName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

In this code, the image (id:imageprofile) is supposed to be aligned to the left
and the TableLayout is supposed to be aligned to the right.

---

Everything works fine except the TableLayout isn't aligning to the left. Whats Wrong?

Comment: show the screenshot.

Comment: I will give me a moment.

Comment: I cant screenshot but the tab layout it aligned to the left and connected to the image and not to the right at the border of the linearlayout.

Comment: where are you using TabLayout n your above code i can't see it.

Comment: What do you mean it is there.

Comment: I mean tablelayout sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try With This

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="140dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
>
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageprofile"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"

        android:layout_margin="35dp" />
    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="15dp">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFullName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </TableRow>
        <TableRow
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/tableRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUserName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="italic" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

`LinearLayout` is not the best parent to use in this case. `layout_gravity` does not work the way you are expecting it to when the orientation is `horizontal` and the view on the right has a width of `wrap_content` and doesn't fill up the entire space as in this case. You should either use `RelativeLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`. Here is an example using `RelativeLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="140dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageprofile"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_margin="35dp"/>

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tablelayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="15dp">

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvFullName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text=""
                android:textSize="30dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvUserName"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textStyle="italic"/>
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Also, you should ensure that you don't duplicate ids within the same layout as you have with the `TableRow`s